# Can I trigger the various camera options in a CameraCaptureUI dialog in my Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, video-capture

I am using the CameraCaptureUI dialog to capture images and video from the camera in my Windows Store App.  I am using an alternative input device, so I want to trigger the various operations in the CameraCaptureUI dialog from my own C# code, instead of having the user click the mouse or use touch to trigger them.  Right now the CameraCaptureUI dialog appears to be a "black box" and I can't see any entry or intercept points.  Is there a way to trigger the various CameraCaptureUI dialog operations (take picture, start video record, stop video record, etc.) from my C# code?

If not, is there a more direct WinRT interface to the camera I can use to to do this myself and if so, what is it called so I can research it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CameraCaptureUI` IS a simplified black box dialog that isn't really part of your app, so you can configure how it gets initialized, but not interact with it with code once it starts.

You can use the `CaptureElement` + `MediaCapture` approach to host a camera preview in your app, but it's quite a bit more work. You can look at my [`CameraCaptureControl`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/CameraCaptureControl/CameraCaptureControl.cs) to find inspiration or simply use it in your app.

Comment: Merged latest WinRTXamlToolkit source code into my project.  For some reason, the ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation extension method is not being picked up by the compiler in ItemsControlHelper.cs, where it's referenced.  I added a using "WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions" statement to ItemsControlHelper.cs, but I am still getting a compiler error.  Everything else compiles fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please ignore that last comment.  Accidentally excluded a file from the project.  It compiles now.